# Error al insertar registros en Tinker / Seeder

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, seeders, tinker

Estoy intentando crear un Seeder en Laravel 8, tengo definida una relacion BelongsToMany para crear una tabla pivot entre una tabla USERS y PROVEEDORES, las relaciones estan definidas de la siguiente forma;

```
// Modelo USER
public function proveedor(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Proveedores::class, 'usuario_proveedor', 'id_usuario', 'id_proveedor')
                    ->using(UsuarioProveedor::class)
                    ->withPivot('usu_insercion', 'usu_modificacion', 'usu_eliminacion')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }

// Modelo PROVEEDORES
 public function usuarios()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'usuario_proveedor', 'id_proveedor', 'id_usuario')
                    ->using(UsuarioProveedor::class)
                    ->withPivot('usu_insercion', 'usu_modificacion', 'usu_eliminacion')
                    ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Utilizo los metodos USING para indicarle el modelo de la tabla PIVOT, esto lo hago porque tengo un TRAIT que inserta datos para auditoria, que son los campos definidos en el metodo withPivot.

El tema es que en el controlador, funciona perfectamente la porcion que asocia estos datos;

```
 // carga la relacion con el proveedor si corresponde
        if ($request->tip_usuario === 'P') {
            $usuario->proveedor()->attach($request->proveedor);
        }
```

Mi problema es cuando intento cargar estos datos con Faker, en un Seeder, o cuando intento asociar un usuario con un proveedor desde Tinker, me aparece el siguiente mensaje;

// Tinker

> > > $user->proveedor()->attach(3)
> > > Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'usu_insercion' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `usuario_proveedor` (`id_proveedor`, `id_usuario`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (3, 62, 2022-02-08 00:37:16, 2022-02-08 00:37:16))'

El codigo del Seeder es;

```
User::factory()->count(5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
      $user->proveedor()->attach(rand(1, 11));
});
```

El error es el siguiente;

```
Seeding: Database\Seeders\UsersSeeder

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'usu_insercion' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `usuario_proveedor` (`id_proveedor`, `id_usuario`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (6, 7, 2022-02-08 00:47:08, 2022-02-08 00:47:08))
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de cual podría ser el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que has definido la tabla intermedia con campos (al menos el campo usu_insercion) que no pueden ser NULOS.

Eso es lo que te dice el error SQL, que no tienes un valor por defecto para el campo usu_insercion en la tabla usuario_proveedor

Tienes 2 opciones:

1 - Si esos campos pueden ser NULOS defínelos como NULL, por ejemplo, en la migración:

```
Schema::table('usuario_proveedor', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
    $table->string('usu_insercion')->nullable();
    ...
});
```

2 - Si los campos han de tener valor (no pueden ser NULOS), pásalos en el seeder, por ejemplo:

```
User::factory()->count(5)->create()->each(function ($user) {
  $user->proveedor()->attach(rand(1, 11), ['usu_insercion' => 'el_valor_que_sea']);
});
```

Esto sin ver las definiciones de los campos en la migración ni saber qué necesitas en esos campos de la tabla intermedia ;-)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!, la verdad es que no puse las migraciones porque pense que se comprendía igual, pero tenes razon, la proxima seré aun mas específico. Por otro lado, como explicaba tengo un Trait aplicado a todos los modelos de mi sistema, que completan el campo usu_insercion, a modo de trigger, pero con tu solucion está perfecto, muchas gracias nuevamente.